# Disabling input units selectively with Keras (Inference Time)

Tags: keras

With Keras, is there a way to selectively disable an input unit at inference time like a dropout layer does randomly during training ?

Comment: Why don't you just set its value to 0?

Comment: because to me 0 as input doesn't mean "disabled" or non-contributing neuron (as far as you are using bias in the layer).

Comment: I don't know what you understand by "disabled", but the neuron does not contribute to the result if its value is zero.

Comment: yes it does if bias is not 0

Comment: Which bias? There is only one bias term for each output neuron (which does not depend on any input neuron). Providing an example (i.e. some formulas) to clarify what is meant by "disabled" neuron might be helpful.

Comment: https://keras.io/layers/core/
Dense implements the operation: output = activation(dot(input, kernel) + bias)

Comment: Thank you, but I am fully aware of this.

Comment: So you understand that setting the input to zero doesn't mean that the neuron isn't contributing to the result as you said ?

Comment: No, that is precisely the bit that I don't understand!